# id.style.display not working

Tags: javascript, css, vb.net

Not sure why this isn't working. There is no js error, but it just doesn't set the display property to "block". If I remove the inner most if statement, the display property for the div control is changed when the last radio button is selected from the group.

.aspx file

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblMarital" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="S" Selected="True">Single</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="M">Married</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="D">Separated/Divorced</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

codebehind

```
If controlId = "rblMarital" Then
    str = "M"
End If

rbl = wizard.FindControl(controlId)
div = wizard.FindControl(temp)
rbl.Attributes.Add("onClick", "showHide('" & rbl.UniqueID & "','" & div.ClientID & "','" & str & "')")
```

javascript

```
function showHide(rbl, div, str) {

    var rblID = document.getElementsByName(rbl);
    var divID = document.getElementById(div);

    for (var j = 0; j < rblID.length; j++) {
        if (rblID[j].checked) {
            if (rblID[j].value == str) {
                divID.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    else
        divID.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

rendered output

```
<td>Marital Status:</td>
<td>
    <table class="noPad formRadioButton">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblMarital" onClick="showHide('_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:wizard1:rblMarital','_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_divMarital','M')" border="0">
                <tr>
            <td><input id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblMarital_0" type="radio" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:wizard1:rblMarital" value="S" checked="checked" /><label for="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblMarital_0">Single</label></td>
                        <td><input id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblMarital_1" type="radio" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:wizard1:rblMarital" value="M" /><label for="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblMarital_1">Married</label></td>
                        <td><input id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblMarital_2" type="radio" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:wizard1:rblMarital" value="D" /><label for="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblMarital_2">Separated/Divorced</label></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_divMarital" style="display:none;">
            <table class="noPad">
                <tr>
                    <td class="back660000">If your spouse is a student</td>
                    <td align="center" style="width:250px;">School <input name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:wizard1:txtSpouseSchool" type="text" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_txtSpouseSchool" style="width:180px;" /></td>
                    <td style="width:180px">Graduation year <input name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:wizard1:txtSpouseGrad" type="text" maxlength="4" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_txtSpouseGrad" style="width:30px;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="back660000">Is your spouse employed</td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table class="formRadioButton">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblSpouseEmployed"><input id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblSpouseEmployed_0" type="radio" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:wizard1:rblSpouseEmployed" value="No" /><label for="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblSpouseEmployed_0">No</label><input id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblSpouseEmployed_1" type="radio" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:wizard1:rblSpouseEmployed" value="Yes" checked="checked" /><label for="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_rblSpouseEmployed_1">Yes</label></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Annual income <input name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:wizard1:txtSpouseIncome" type="text" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizard1_txtSpouseIncome" style="width:100px;" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you post the rendered output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out as I looked more closely at my code, the else statement was in the wrong place.

```
function showHide(rbl, div, str) {

        var rblID = document.getElementsByName(rbl);
        var divID = document.getElementById(div);

        for (var j = 0; j < rblID.length; j++) {
            if (rblID[j].checked) {
                if (rblID[j].value == str) {
                    divID.style.display = "block";
                }
                else
                    divID.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no name attribute on your rbl (or does .Net put one on there for you):

```
function showHide(rbl, div, str) {

    var rblID = document.getElementById(rbl);
    var divID = document.getElementById(div);

    if (rblID.value == str) {
        divID.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        divID.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

Comment: The name is set the same as the uniqueid when the page is rendered by the server. It is my understanding that in order to target a collection of radio buttons, you need to reference it by the name. Finally, everything works without issues if I remove the if(rblid[j].vlaue == str) conditional statement, although this functionality causes issues when I have multiple radio buttons as it displays the div when the last radio button is checked

Answer (score 0):

Are you definitely setting the name property of radio button group? I can't see anything wrong with that straight off. Check the value of str and rblID[j] inside the first if statement

Are you getting what you expect??

Comment: Yes, alerting str prompts 'M', alerting rblID[j].value prompts 'M' as well, I placed an alert inside the nested conditional statement and the alert method fires just fine so I know the conditions are true, it's just that the display property isn't being set and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you want to have the div visible when the "married" option is selected and hidden when anything else is selection. The way you have it written, the "seperated" option is always the last item checked. When you pick "married" the div is immediately set `display:block` and then back to `display:none` because "seperated" is not checked.

A quick fix is to hide the div by default and then show it if "married" is the selected item.

```
function showHide(rbl, div, str) {

    var rblID = document.getElementsByName(rbl);
    var divID = document.getElementById(div);

    divID.style.display = "none";

    for (var j = 0; j < rblID.length; j++) {
        if (rblID[j].checked && rblID[j].value === str) {
            divID.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for an answer that would work, although I found the solution.